# react-native can't build run android correctly

Tags: android, android-studio, react-native, android-gradle-plugin

I was trying to run an android project with this command:

```
react-native run-android
```

but it doesn't build anything and print this msg:

```
Starting JS server...
Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && gradlew.bat installDebug)...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not download javax.inject.jar (javax.inject:javax.inject:1)
   > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/javax/inject/javax.inject/1/javax.inject-1.jar'.
      > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/javax/inject/javax.inject/1/javax.inject-1.jar'.
         > Connect to jcenter.bintray.com:443 [jcenter.bintray.com/108.168.243.150] failed: Connection timed
t: connect

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log outpu

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 2 mins 17.303 secs
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-setup.html
```

how can I fix it?

Comment: why do u need java.inject.jar? remove it and it will solve your problem?

Comment: I don't know & where is this?

Comment: You can try `./gradlew clean` and then `./gradlew build` and turn on your emulator first `react-native run-android`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as you can see, you need to run your android simulator first or connect to a device.

so in your terminal 
type:

```
android avd
```

then create a device if you dont have one, then start it.
If the simulator has run, then you can start building by typing

```
react-native run-android
```